# Using System.Web.Helpers in a WPF desktop application

Tags: json, wpf, dll

I have been working on a WPF desktop application remotely. Everything has worked great so far, but recently I had to move some functionality from a web application to the WPF application. It uses the [`System.Web.Helpers.Json` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx) to decode some JSON that comes from a website CMS system.

I therefore added a reference to the `System.Web.Helpers` dll to the project along with the relevant code and when I ran it locally, it all worked fabulously. Unfortunately, after deploying it using Click Once, the users got the following error:

[image]

So I added a reference to the `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` dll file to the project, ensured that it would be copied locally and then deployed a new version of the application. Unfortunately, the following day, I was presented with a new error:

[image]

I've searched online and found that if I add a reference to the `System.Web.Razor` dll, then that will in turn require a reference to the `System.Web` dll. My problem is that due to time constraints, I only get to make one change a day and this needs to be fixed as soon as possible... if I only get informed about one missing reference each day, then I could run out of time really easily.

So my question is *does anyone know all the references that I will need to add to satisfy the `System.Web.Helpers` dll*?

Comment: If  you're just parsing JSON, why not just use [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: I thought of that, but the company is not keen on using third party dlls. It's good to see you're still around here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this question and realised that I never updated it with an answer. Unfortunately, this was asked a long time ago, so I can't be 100% sure of this answer now, but from what I can remember, I needed to add these following DLLs in order to use the `System.Web.Helpers` assembly:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

There is a possibility that you'll also need the `System.Web` and `System.Web.WebPages.Administration` assemblies, but I can't be 100% sure about that now.